# How to make analyzeGPS distanceGPS group by trip?

Tags: r, gps, grouping

I have a dataset with `id, lat, lon and time`, where each trip has a unique `id`.

When I try to use [mutate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/mutate) with the [distanceGPS function](https://github.com/ehrscape/R-project/blob/master/AnalyzeGPS/man/distanceGPS.Rd) in the [AnalyzeGPS package](https://github.com/ehrscape/R-project/blob/master/AnalyzeGPS/DESCRIPTION) and [group by](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/group_by) trip using this code:

```
gps%>%group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>%mutate(d <- c(0, 
  distanceGPS(lat1 = lat[1:(n()-1)], 
              lon1 = lon[1:(n()-1)], 
              lat2 = lat[2:n()], 
              lon2 = lon[2:n()]
              )
              )
  )​
```

I get this error:
`Error Colum ...<-NULL must be lenght 1(group size), not 3`

This works:

```
d <- distanceGPS(lat1 = gps$lat[1:(length(gps$lat) - 1)], 
                 lon1 = gps$lon[1:(length(gps$lon) -1)], 
                 lat2 = gps$lat[2:length(gps$lat)], 
                 lon2 = gps$lon[2:length(gps$lon)])
trips$d <- c(0, d)​
```

... but it just has one trip with multiple points.

Comment: How is it "Not working"? What is your input data? What for do you expect your output to be? What are you getting instead?

Comment: Where does the `analyzeGPS` package come from? Its not on CRAN.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman , in fact not working means what i did is not correct, I think my probel is with the code itself, not with the library analyseGPS
[link](https://github.com/ehrscape/R-project/blob/master/AnalyzeGPS-walkthrough.md)
What I actually need is to use an operation inside mutate (Here calculating the distance between each consecutive points for each trip)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266430/using-the-result-of-summarise-dplyr-to-mutate-the-original-dataframe